# search by date mysql performance

Tags: mysql

I have a large table with about 100 million records, with fields `start_date` and `end_date`, with `DATE` type. I need to check the number of overlaps with some date range, say between `2013-08-20` AND `2013-08-30`, So I use.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myTable WHERE end_date >= '2013-08-20' 
AND start_date <= '2013-08-30'
```

date column are indexed.
The important points is that the date ranges that I am searching for overlap are always in the future, while the main part of the records in the table are in the past (say about 97-99 million).
So, will this query be faster, if I add a column `is_future - TINYINT`, so, by checking only that condition like this

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myTable WHERE is_future = 1 
AND end_date >= '2013-08-20' AND start_date <= '2013-08-30'
```

it will exclude the rest 97 million or so records and will check the date condition for only the remaining 1-3 million records ?

I use MySQL

Thanks

**EDIT**

The mysql engine is innodb, but will matter considerably if it is say, MyISAM

here is the create table

```
CREATE TABLE `orders` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title`
  `start_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `end_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=24 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
```

**EDIT 2** after @Robert Co answer

The partitioning looks like a good idea for this case, but it does not allow me to create partition based on `is_future` field unless I define it as primary key, otherwise I should remove my main primary key - id, which I can not do. So, if I define that field as primary key, then is there a meaning of partitioning, will not it be fast already if I search by `is_future` field which is primary key.

**EDIT 3**
The actual query where I need to use this is to select restaurant that have some free tables for that date range

```
SELECT r.id, r.name, r.table_count
FROM restaurants r
LEFT JOIN orders o 
ON r.id = o.restaurant_id 
WHERE o.id IS NULL 
OR (r.table_count > (SELECT COUNT(*) 
                FROM orders o2 
                WHERE o2.restaurant_id = r.id AND
                end_date >= '2013-08-20' AND start_date <= '2013-08-30'
                AND o2.status = 1
            )
)
```

**SOLUTION**
After a lot more research and testing the fastest way for counting the number of rows in my case was to just add one more condition, that start_date is more than current date (because the date ranges for search are always in the future)

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myTable WHERE end_date >= '2013-09-01' 
         AND start_date >= '2013-08-20' AND start_date <= '2013-09-30'
```

also it is necessary to have one index - with start_date and end_date fields (thank you @symcbean).
As a result the execution time on table with 10m rows from 7 seconds - became 0.050 seconds.

**SOLUTION 2** (@Robert Co)
partitioning in this case worked as well !! - perhaps it is better solution than indexing. Or they can both be applied together.

Thanks

Comment: Great question... try it and let us know. ;) Why are you not using `BETWEEN`?

Comment: @DevlshOne, :D, how to use between in this case ? I compare 2 columns , can I ?

Comment: Can you post the create table statement and information about storage engine, this matters..

Comment: first do you really need that bigint... because when you index start_date and end_date / is_future. InnoDB will add the PRIMARY KEY data to that index (extra 8 bytes), on 100 Million records that would save diskspace / smaller indexes what in thoery should perform better

Comment: @RaymondNijland, I guess u r right, the db was going to be big, but I guess it won't be more than 4 billions, so the int should be ok.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a perfect use case for 
[table partitioning](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning-range.html). If the Oracle INTERVAL feature makes it to MySQL, then it will just add to the awesomeness.

Comment: Not really sure why you think an 'order' table disqualify it from partitioning. You can create the partitions ahead of time, in case you don't want the data to fall into the MAXVALUE.

Comment: Partitioning key doesn't have to be the same as the primary key. If you choose partitioning, you no longer need the is_future flag. I would partition by the end date. Don't overdo the partitioning. Monthly should be enough.

Comment: but, see, if every month the orders are being added and the older once go to "past", so every month I should add a new partition, should not I ? is not it bad? Thanks

Comment: You specify the date range that fits into that partition. So you can pre-create 12 partitions per year (or many more years). It will only take up space when it starts getting data.

Answer (score 2):

> date column are indexed

What type of index? A hash based index is no use for range queries. If it's not a BTREE index then change it now. And you've not shown us **how* they are indexed. Are both columns in the same index? Is there other stuff in there too? What order (end_date must appear as the first column)?

There are implicit type conversions in the script - this *should* be handled automatically by the optimizer, but it's worth checking....

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myTable WHERE end_date >= 20130820000000 
AND start_date <= 20130830235959
```

> if I add a column is_future - TINYINT

First, in order to be of any use, this would require that the future dates be a small proportion of the total data stored in the table (less than 10%). And that's just to make it more efficient than a full table scan.

Secondly, it's going to require very frequent updates to the index to maintain it, which in addition to the overhead of initial populatiopn is likely to lead to fragmentation of the index and degraded performance (depending on how the iondex is constructed).

Thirdly, if this still has to process 3 million rows of data (and specifically, via an index lookup) then it's going to be very slow even with the data pegged in memory.

Further, the optimizer is never likely to use this index without being forced to (due to the low cardinality).

Comment: I updated the question. About index - it is a usual index that is being created by `ALTER TABLE orders ADD INDEX endDate (end_date);`, the same for `start_date`, is not it right ?

Comment: That doesn't answer the question about what type of index it is - but you'll find that dropping these and replacing with a single index on (end_date, start_date, ...) will work a lot better. And given the fursther information you've provided it should probably be (end_date, start_date, restaurant_id). The query you are using for finding tables is far from optimal

Comment: but than what is the way to find out what type of index it is ? without replacing index with single index what else can I do to make this query optimized ? or I can find the restaurants with free tables with other query ? THanks

Answer (score 0):

I have done a simple test, just created an index on the tinyint column.  The structures may not be the same, but with an index it seems to work.

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/514ab/1/0
and for count 
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/514ab/2/0

View execution plan there to see that the select just scans one row which means it would process only the lesser number of records in your case.

So the simple answer is yes, with an index it would work.

Comment: No you don't index a column with a low selectivity only two values 0 - 1 should never be indexed..

Comment: Ok I learnt something, but then the answer is NO, because without the index it selects all the three rows, I guess the answer is then obvious

Comment: @RaymondNijland, unless you want the column to be in the covering index, otherwise it will require (mostly random) disk io for each row. Never say never.

Comment: @newtover true but a covering index will always result in a higher selectivity.